# The "HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL" constant is deprecated since Symfony 5.2

Tags: php, symfony, http-headers, symfony5, symfony5.4

I have just upgraded to Symfony 5.4 and i'm hitting a deprecation notice on my usage of the `HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL` constant.

```php
trigger_deprecation('symfony/http-foundation', '5.2', 'The "HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL" constant is deprecated, use either "HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR | HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST | HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT | HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" or "HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB" or "HEADER_X_FORWARDED_TRAEFIK" constants instead.');
```

Up until now I have be calling `setTrustedProxies` with the following:

```php
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL);
```

What is the recommended approach for getting rid of this? I am looking at calling `setTrustedProxies` for each header, but i'm not sure if that's correct. There's nothing clear in the documentation around this.

```php
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO);
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT);
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PREFIX);
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB);
```

Is `HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR` enough? (I also have the application sitting behind an ELB).

Comment: This [PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/38954) should have an answer for you hopefully

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks for the link. `Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR` doesn't cover everything, does it?

Comment: No, but there’s also HOST, PORT and PROTO, as well as two stack-specific ones, AWS_ELB and TRAEFIK.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm not sure if calling `setTrustedProxies` multiple times will do what `_ALL` used to do...

Comment: I’d assume calling multiple times would override each time, it looks like you are supposed to OR (`|`) them together in a single call

Comment: @ChrisHaas Oh, sorry. I misread that. I thought the `|` was options rather than the actual syntax. Thanks